# how to operate a loop over extracted data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I received 10 name strings from mysqldb to $.Ajax (function(data) now how to split that (data) as it is echoing all the 10 names in one div i want to echo it in 10 different divs

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();  
    //console.log("you clicked"+txt);
        $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'thegamer.php',
    data: {send_txt: txt},
    success: function( data ){
    //now echo the data where you want
    // for example
       $('#sliderid').html( data );
    // or you can see in on firebug
    console.log( 'Return:' + data );
        }               
 });
});
});
```

my php code

```
 $family = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['send_txt'], $link);
$query = "SELECT imgurl FROM images WHERE family='$family'";

//Query database
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

//Output result, send back to ajax as var 'response'
$i=0;
echo "<table>";
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['imgurl']."</td></tr>";
        $i+=1;
    }
}else{
    echo "<tr><td>No results matching family \"$family\"</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: please post some example code... we can't guess.

Comment: Include your current code and a sample of the data you are receiving from the backend.

Comment: there are no <div> in the code, so what block is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

1) you can do it in the php side: e.g. :

```
foreach($rows as $row) 
{
   $return_data .= '<div>' . $row['name'] . '</div>';
}
```

2) you can return the data as JSON (using  json_encode() in php) and then loop through it in js